Blank white screen when maximizing application on 4k monitor
I have a problem on my laptop when maximizing every window on my external 4k Dell S2721QS monitor.
If I do that, the screen becomes blank, white.
I'm still able to use the cursor, and if I minimize the window, the screen comes back to be visible.
Still, this behavior doesn't start immediately after login, but I didn't realize what triggers that.
Sometimes it also happens that after waking up from suspend, both laptop and external 4k monitor are blank, and there's no way to fix that, except rebooting.
My laptop specs:
OS Ubuntu 24.04
Kernel Linux 6.8.0-31-generic
Gnome 46
Wayland
CPU AMD Ryzen 7 8845HS w/ Radeon 780M Graphics
RAM 32GB DDR5

Output of lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Phoenix3
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: c5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 mode=2560x1600 resolution=3840,2160 visual=truecolor xres=2560 yres=1600
       resources: iomemory:800-7ff irq:42 memory:80c0000000-80cfffffff memory:a0000000-a01fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:a0500000-a057ffff

Any idea on how to debug/fix that?
Thanks!

Please edit the question and add the info about the graphics driver you are using.

@David I updated my question

It seems the problem is related with the scatter-gather display support in the AMDGPU driver.
To fix the issue on Ubuntu, edit the file /etc/default/grub changing to following line
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

to
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.sg_display=0"

